# Move from Stack Overflow to sharepoint.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Since my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084647/is-there-a-way-to-extract-column-header-and-filters-from-a-list-in-sharepoint-us) has no responses, and is SharePoint related, is there a way to move it to `sharepoint.stackexchange.com`?

Or somehow crosslink it for the question to get more views there?

Or do I just have to repost the question there?

Comment: You should ask this question in Meta , there someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your question and repost there. This would also belong in http://meta.stackexchange.com